# Using .net core, how can i show the html content coming from database on view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the business login written in `Application_BeginRequest` method of `Global.asax` file where i get an html content from database and set the content at view using literal control.

Now i am migrating the project into .net core where i want the same thing to do as mentioned above. I have got the html content in the code using `middleware` but now i am trying to show the content on view but unable to do so.

Following is my model

```
@model string
<div id="content">@Model</div>
```

and i am returning

```
return View(html);
```

as a string.

My question is, i want to know the steps that how can i show the html content coming from database on view using .net core.

Comment: You can use `@Html.Raw(Model)` to render html string.

Comment: I think it will not work in .net core. I have tried but it shows An unhandled "exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)" error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Got the solution. i was missing the model. I declared the model and then passed that model to the view and then used `@Html.Raw(@Model.Property)` at view to render the HTML.

Thanks @adem caglin.

Comment: Not sure about 1.x, but in .NET Core 2.0 you don't need the second @ (It works both ways though)